# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am fetching json data from an api using retrofit.But when i am running app it's showing an error `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $`.I dont know whats the problem.Here is my json data:

```html
{"status":true,"message":"Notifications fetched.","data":
 [{"id":"69","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0",
"username":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""},
{"id":"64","type":"liked","text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your 
photo.","for_userid":"56","from_userid":"55","for_image":"54","seen":"0","userna
me":"sandip","firstname":"Sandip","lastname":"Ghosh","imgname":""}]}
```

and my interface class:

```html
  public static final String BASE_URL = "http://chikoop.com/api/index.php/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

   static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like there is some issue with your json data. Few new line characters have been placed in between the data which is causing the issue. For ex one new line character is present in `"text":"Sandip Ghosh liked your 
photo."` after your. Below is the valid json. You can check for the validity of json  [here.](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Notifications fetched.",
"data": [{
    "id": "69",
    "type": "liked",
    "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
    "for_userid": "56",
    "from_userid": "55",
    "for_image": "54",
    "seen": "0",
    "username": "sandip",
    "firstname": "Sandip",
    "lastname": "Ghosh",
    "imgname": ""
}, {
    "id": "64",
    "type": "liked",
    "text": "Sandip Ghosh liked your photo.",
    "for_userid": "56",
    "from_userid": "55",
    "for_image": "54",
    "seen": "0",
    "username": "sandip",
    "firstname": "Sandip",
    "lastname": "Ghosh",
    "imgname": ""
}]
}
```

Comment: no its the same ,it is created by me .I mean the json data you present is same i have.

Comment: indeed it's same by data, but it is not valid. You can check both json here http://jsonlint.com/ or http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. You will get to know what is the error.

Comment: no,it is correct other one who are working on same project fetch the same json data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the API, try tweaking your response. I tried using Gson and retrofit and for me it failed spectacularly
Or you could try using

Okhttp client = new okhttp()
Retrofit = new retrofit.builder(). BaseUrl(your URL)
. Setclient (client).addconverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)). Build

Comment: srry but syntax is not correct can u write it more clear.